# What is the most universal 3D file format?

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality

After googling I learned there are different 3D files

1. *.obj & *.mtl    (Wavefront)
2. *.dae    (Collada)
3. *.u3d      (Universal format)
4. *.3ds      (3D Studio Max)
5. *.ma, *.mb  (Maya  files)
6. *.blend   (Blender)
   and many more.

Just wanted to know which one is most used file in Augmented Reality application?

Answer (score 0):

I would say OBJ. It's commonly used in CAD, gaming and movie industries.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the FBX format. Most of the 3D software can import/export it so it's often used to exchange data between applications.

OBJ format is also very common but I believe it's simpler, so it depends on your needs. If you're fine with OBJ functionality then go for it, it would be easier to work with but if it lacks any features you need then FBX will probably support them.